# Remove rows based on duplicate field in column

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table with fields like this

```
F1  F2   F3  F4
1    4    A   5
2    4    A   5
3    4    B   5
4    4    C   5
5    4    D   5
```

I would like to delete all rows where F3 is a duplicate, so in order to get no duplicate values in field F3:

```
F1  F2   F3  F4
1    4    A   5
3    4    B   5
4    4    C   5
5    4    D   5
```

Thx!

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregation:

```
select any_value(f1), any_value(f2), f3, any_value(f4)
from t
group by f3;
```

If you want all the values to be from a particular row, you can use `row_number()`:

```
select t.* except (seqnum)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by f3 order by f3) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t;
```

You can adjust the `order by` key to specify which row you want to keep (say the largest `f1` value or whatever).

And another method is:

```
select as value any_value(t)
from t
group by f3;
```

Comment: Apparently BigQuery does not support any_value:

ERROR: Unrecognized function any_value

Comment: @EGM8686 . . . It certainly does:  https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#any_value.

Comment: I know, however I get this error:

Query Failed
Error: 1.17 - 1.24: Unrecognized function any_value

Comment: @EGM8686 . . . Be sure you are using Standard SQL.

Comment: ANY VALUE only works in for STANDARD SQL however the result is too large for BigQuery to return a result so it's recommending to move to LEGACY SQL which does not support ANY VALUE.

Comment: @EGM8686 . . . What about `row_number()`?  I have not had BigQuery recommend legacy SQL for any queries.  How big is your data?

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT AS VALUE ANY_VALUE(t)
FROM `project.dataset.table` t
GROUP BY F3
```

You can test, play with above using sample data from your question as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1 F1, 4 F2, 'A' F3, 5 F4 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 4, 'A', 5 UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 4, 'B', 5 UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 4, 'C', 5 UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, 4, 'D', 5 
)
SELECT AS VALUE ANY_VALUE(t)
FROM `project.dataset.table` t
GROUP BY F3
```

with result

```
Row F1  F2  F3  F4   
1   1   4   A   5    
2   3   4   B   5    
3   4   4   C   5    
4   5   4   D   5
```

Comment: ANY VALUE only works in for STANDARD SQL however the result is too large for BigQuery to return a result so it's recommending to move to LEGACY SQL which does not support ANY VALUE

Comment: Lol. Have you tried? Does it return error? What it is?